# How do I get the hexadecimal value from a Color object in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, colors, hex, uint

So I am  making a music visualizer and I am trying to set the linestyle for my graphics to be a pre defined color! But I get an error when trying

```
var lineColor:Color = new Color(120,120,12);
graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness, lineColor);
```

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.motion:Color to an unrelated type uint.

So then I tried

```
var lineColor:Color = new Color(120,120,12);
graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness, lineColor.color);
```

But `lineColor.color` always returns 0! What do I do? I can't believe there is no built in API to take a color object and make it a compatible hexadecimal uint for graphics!

Any help would be much apprectiated!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a method to return the hex value.

```
function get_uint_from_colour(red:int, green:int, blue:int) {

    return red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;

}
```

So in your example:

```
graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness, get_uint_from_colour(120, 120, 12));
```

In response to your comment about needing to use a set of pre-defined `Color` objects, you will still need to (at some point) convert them to the type `uint` as this is the accepted data-type for the `lineStyle` method.

My suggestion would be to adjust the `get_uint_from_colour` method to accept a `Color` object. Like so:

```
function get_uint_from_colour(colour:Color) {

    return int(colour.redMultiplier) << 16 | int(colour.greenMultiplier) << 8 | int(colour.blueMultiplier);

}
```

So in your code:

```
graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness, get_uint_from_colour(lineColor));
```

**Please note that I have changed the name of my original method as I felt it better describes the function**

**Also, keep in mind that a `Color` object can hold much more information about itself than a standard Hex colour can - this superfluous information will be lost in the process of converting it.**

Comment: Thanks! Thats one way to solve the problem. But is there a way to uses the Color object specifically. Because I have multiple color variables in this class I am using.